# How to disable certain days of the week on a jQuery datepicker based on a result in a database with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I have a **mySQL** database with a table of staff information and what days of the week they work i.e Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday.

I have an **HTML** from which allows user to book an appoint, the idea is based on who they want the **appointment** with would depend what days they can chose from within the **jquery** datepicker.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" required="required" value="Name">
     <select id="SelectStylest" name="stylest">

`<?php 

     $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Name FROM staff") or die(mysqli_error());

      while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){

        echo "<option value='".$row['Name']."'>".$row['Name']."</option>";

      }

    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="appointment_date"id="datepicker">

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

```html
          
          $( function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
             $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
                minTime: "09:00",
                maxTime: "17:00"
               
             });
            });
```

I know I need to following query to search the database to friend the name of the stylist, but after that I get lost. I have googled the problem but haven't found anything on the subject.

```
$stylest = $_POST['stylest'];

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM staff WHERE Name LIKE '%$stylest%'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [`beforeShowDay`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option in date picker. For example this enables only Tuesdays Wednesdays and Fridays:

```
workingDays = [2, 3, 5];

$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: function (date) {
      return [workingDays.indexOf(date.getDay()) > -1];
  }
});
```

Day of week as returned by Date go from Sunday=0 to Saturday=6.

---

To transform your current `working_days` format to the numeric `workingDays` array needed in JS, you can use:

```
<?php
... // get row from mysqli_fetch_assoc
$weekDays = explode(',', $row['working_days']);
$days = [];
foreach ($weekDays as $d) {
    if ($d == 'Sunday') $days[] = 0;
    if ($d == 'Monday') $days[] = 1;
    // ... and so on
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">workingDays='.json_encode($days).'</script>';
?>
```

Comment: yes but if a member of staff days to work change I only want them to be picked up from the database so that they don't have to edit any code. I want the information to simply be changed in the database. This code wouldn't work as there is more than one member of staff.

Comment: Yes [2,3,5] was just an example. You have to figure out how to get it from your database. If you need help with that part, you have to include more information in the question, for example how the workers' schedules are stored in your database.

Comment: I have updated my question so you can now see my database

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: it seems now to start on Sunday no matter what numbers in in the WorkingDays javascript array.

Comment: Oh I misremembered how the `in` operator works in JS, you'll want to use `workingDays.includes(date.getDay())` or `indexOf` instead. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

this will disable weekend days and a select list of holidays

```
var disabledDays = ["2018-11-22","2018-11-23","2018-12-24","2018-12-25", "2019-01-01"]

$( "input#ship_date" ).datepicker({   
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        var day = date.getDay();        
        return [ day != 0 && day != 6 && disabledDays.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});
```